# Wrong checked checkboxes after ajax call based on radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, synchronization

I have a list of checkboxes which are checked or unchecked based on 3 radio buttons. When the selected radio button changes, an ajax request determines which checkboxes will be checked based on the selected radio button (its value)

However, when I change the selection of 2 radio buttons a little quickly, the boxes that are checked are those of as if I had selected the 2 radio buttons at the same time.

checked checkboxes when "manager" is selected :
[Manager selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY5di.png)

checked checkboxes when "test" is selected :
[test selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIWAm.png)

Problem ->
checked checkbox when I select "manager" then "test" quickly :
[manager then test selected quickly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rNoR.png)
But the last selected is "test" so I need have checked checkbox for "test" not "test" and "manager" in same time.

Here my JS code :

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[type=radio][name=\"user[profile]\"]", function (){

        let value = $( this ).val();
        let data = {profile_id: value}
        let url = HOME_URL + '/API/getmodules/' + value

        $('input:checkbox[id^="user_access_"]').prop('checked', false) //initialize all checkboxes at uncheck
        $('span[class^="badge badge-success"]:not([id^="span-example"])').contents().unwrap();

        $.post(url, data).then(function (response)
        {

            let modulesData = response.modules
            for (let module in modulesData){
                let moduleValue = modulesData[module].id

                let $modules = $('input:checkbox[id^="user_access_"][value=' + moduleValue + ']')
                let $modulesLabel = $('label[for="user_access_' + modulesData[module].toolId + '_' + moduleValue + '"]')

                $modules.prop('checked', true) // check the checkboxes depends on the data response
                $modulesLabel.empty();
                $modulesLabel.append('<span class="badge badge-success">' + modulesData[module].name + '</span>');
            }

        })

    })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your post callback `then()` you need to check if the callback is still for the "current" situation.  Simplest check seems to be to include the user profile id in the response data and check response.profile_id === data.profile_id.   You can do this in the ajax request data, but easier/clearer/most robust to do this in your own code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem (I still have the checkboxes that shouldn't be checked). I put the test code in my question.

Comment: Ah - this is because `let data = profile_id` is updated each `change` event, but only *within that change event* - due to the `let` being within the `function(){` part.  My bad for not clarifying.  Either move the "current" situation variable to the outer scope (eg make it global) so there's only one or, possibly clearer, re-get it within the callback, eg `current_profile_id = $("input[type=radio][name=\"user[profile]\"]:checked").val()`

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much, I wouldn't have figured out how to do it on my own!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution ! Thanks to freedomn-m !

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[type=radio][name=\"user[profile]\"]", function (){

        let value = $( this ).val();
        let data = {profile_id: value}
        let url = HOME_URL + '/API/getmodules/' + value
        // console.log(data.profile_id)

        $('input:checkbox[id^="user_access_"]').prop('checked', false) //initialize checkbox at uncheck
        $('span[class^="badge badge-success"]:not([id^="span-example"])').contents().unwrap();

        $.post(url, data).then(function (response)
        {
            console.log("response : " + response.profile_id + ", data : " + data.profile_id)

            let current_profile_id = $("input[type=radio][name=\"user[profile]\"]:checked").val()
            if(response.profile_id == current_profile_id){
                let modulesData = response.modules
                for (let module in modulesData){
                    let moduleValue = modulesData[module].id

                    let $modules = $('input:checkbox[id^="user_access_"][value=' + moduleValue + ']')
                    let $modulesLabel = $('label[for="user_access_' + modulesData[module].toolId + '_' + moduleValue + '"]')

                    $modules.prop('checked', true) // check the checkboxes depends on the data response
                    $modulesLabel.empty();
                    $modulesLabel.append('<span class="badge badge-success">' + modulesData[module].name + '</span>');
                }
            } else{ console.log("ERROR")}

        })

    })
```